# Bash: cross-join files with custom combination symbol

Tags: bash

I have a file with a lines of non-consecutive dates:

```
2020-07-01
2020-07-04
2020-07-05
```

And another file with hours of interest for any of those dates:

```
0
5
6
12
18
```

I'd like to combine these into a file that cross-joins the files:

```
2020-07-01-0
2020-07-01-5
2020-07-01-6
2020-07-01-12
2020-07-01-18
2020-07-04-0
2020-07-04-5
...
```

Is there a neat way in Bash to do that? `join` does not appear to do what I want and I could just loop through both, but I was wondering if there is some one-line magic I'm not aware of that would make this super simple.

Answer (score 2):

This could be easily achieved with `awk`:

```
$ cat f1
0
5
6
12
18

$ cat f2
2020-07-01
2020-07-04
2020-07-05

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[i++]=$1;next}{for (j=0;j<i;j++){print $1"-"a[j]}}' f1 f2
2020-07-01-0
2020-07-01-5
2020-07-01-6
2020-07-01-12
2020-07-01-18
2020-07-04-0
2020-07-04-5
2020-07-04-6
2020-07-04-12
2020-07-04-18
2020-07-05-0
2020-07-05-5
2020-07-05-6
2020-07-05-12
2020-07-05-18
```

Answer (score 0):

A slow bash solution for large set of files/data but it will get you there, slowly but surely.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -ru9 file2; do
  while read -r file1; do
    printf '%s-%s\n' "$file2" "$file1"
  done < f1 
done 9< f2
```

The one-liner.

```sh
while read -ru9 file2; do while read -r file1; do printf '%s-%s\n' "$file2" "$file1"; done < f1; done 9< f2
```